# Why doesn't autovideosink displays video on connected Qt5' QVideoWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gstreamer, qwidget

I have linked a pipeline that works correctly.
It contains a:

1. playbin2
2. tee -> outputs on udp branch (not relevant) and video branch, which contains:
3. queue
4. videoconvert (ffmpegcolorspace)
5. **autovideosink**

I know it works correctly because the media is sent to the autovideosink, yet the problem is that my application opens a "GStreamer Direct3D sink default window" and outputs the video there.

The autovideosink is connected to the QVideoWidget with:

```
video_widget_1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true); // this is a QVideoWidget, still, this may be unnecessary
WId win_1_id = video_widget_1->winId();
QApplication::sync(); // may be unnecessary
gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_X_OVERLAY(data->el_autovideo_snk_1), win_1_id);
```

**I don't plan to use QtGstreamer since I found it very difficult to install.**

If I set a simple pipeline containing only a playbin2, and I connect it to the videowidget, the media gets correctly displayed into the widget.

**So playbin2 correctly outputs to the videowidget, but autovideosink no. Why?**

Am I missing anything? Or is there an alternative to autovideosink?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using GStreamer in a Qt application instead of Qt Multimedia?

Comment: It was required by the specification of my BA project to use gstreamer pipelines @MrEricSir

Comment: Can I stream media content from url/device/file from one computer to another (on the same LAN) with QtMultimedia, without gstreamer??? @MrEricSir

Comment: Don't see why not, Qt provides a fairly comprehensive network stack.

Comment: @MrEricSir still I have to use gstreamer, and half of my project uses it. playbin correctly outputs to the video widget, autovideosink no, it opens another video, even though its linked to a videoconvert